# UnicodeDecodeError when cleaning text data

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, nlp, gensim

I am trying to clean some text. I am keeping alphabets and numbers only. However, my text still contains other characters.

This is my function:

```
def review_to_wordlist(review, remove_stopwords=False, remove_numbers = False ):
# Function to convert a document to a sequence of words,
# optionally removing stop words and numbers.  Returns a list of words.
#
# 1. Remove HTML
review_text = BeautifulSoup(review).get_text()
#
# 2. Remove non-letters
if True:
    review_text = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9]"," ", review_text)
#
# 3. Convert words to lower case and split them
words = review_text.lower().split()
#
# 4. Optionally remove stop words (false by default)
if remove_stopwords:
    stops = set(stopwords.words("english"))
    words = [w for w in words if not w in stops]
#
# 5. Return a list of words
return(words)
```

and this is one result that I get:

> NuTone Central Vacuum System 45� Ell Ohio Steel Tandem Natural and
>   Synthetic Turf Sweeping System Unique Home Designs 36 in. x 80 in. Su
>   Casa Black Surface Mount Outswing Steel Security Door with Expanded
>   Metal Screen Unique Home Designs 36 in. x 80 in. Su Casa Black Surface
>   Mount Outswing Steel Security Door with Expanded Metal Screen Unique
>   Home Designs 36 in. x 80 in. Su Casa Black Surface Mount Outswing
>   Steel Security Door with Expanded Metal Screen MP Global Best 400 in.
>   x 36 in. x 1/8 in. Acoustical Recycled Fiber Underlayment with Film
>   for Laminate Wood MP Global Best 400 in. x 36 in. x 1/8 in. Acoustical
>   Recycled Fiber Underlayment with Film for Laminate Wood Grip-Rite
>   #10-1/4 in. x 2-1/2 in. 8� Bright Steel Ring-Shank Common Nails (1 lb.-Pack)

the error that I get is:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 5-6: unexpected end of data


676
Husky Pneumatic 3-1/2 in. 21� Full-Head Strip Framing Nailer
5157
RIDGID 3-1/2 in. 21� Round-Head Nailer
5158
RIDGID 3-1/2 in. 21� Round-Head Nailer
```

Comment: What is the page encoding and how are you getting the source?

Comment: Is it python 2 or 3? and when exactly do you get that error?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham : the line in the file looks like "25598,105177,"Grip-Rite #10-1/4 in. x 2-1/2 in. 8Â° Bright Steel Ring-Shank Common Nails (1 lb.-Pack)","4' steel ring",2". How can I ignore such characters "Â°"

Comment: @ahmed I am using python 2.7

Comment: So you are reading from a file?

Comment: yes  @Padraic Cunningham

Comment: What line causes the Unidecode error?

Comment: quite a few. Should I find the exact line number? @Padraic Cunningham

Comment: @MAS yes, it would help to know what you are doing when it errors, more than likely you are using the wrong encoding, where did the data come from?

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: @Padraic CunninghamI am reading it through pandas. so the number represent the row of my data frame and the text is the corresponding content. I added my original post in the answer. Here it looks messy

Comment: So pd.read_csv? try setting `encoding="latin-1"`

Comment: @ Padraic Cunningham yes, it worked. Thank you!

Comment: No worries, read_csv defaults to utf8, wherever the data came from must have been using latin1 as the charset.

Answer (score 0):

From the [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35252743/unicodedecodeerror-when-cleaning-text-data#comment58219200_35252743) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35252743/unicodedecodeerror-when-cleaning-text-data#comment58219404_35252743) of Padraic Cunningham, `pd.read_csv` defaults to utf8 when reading. This can cause some characters to become garbled, and can be fixed by setting `encoding="latin-1"` in the call.